# Pricing tier vs Service tier vs Instance size

Tags: azure

I am finding the terms pricing tier, service tier and instance sizes very confusing. Could you please explain them with probably an example? I have read posts where 2 "large" instances using in a "Basic" tier. 
Now, by large instance, it would mean A3 (4 cores, 7 GB RAM) (as mentioned [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/cloud-services-sizes-specs/)). Then again, it mentions they are using basic tier (1 core, 1.75 GB RAM).

What is the relation?

Thanks!

Comment: You already indicated using Azure in the tags, there is no need to add it explicitly to the title. Also, this is not the place to ask this.

Answer (score 1):

Virtual machines in Azure can be either on Basic or Standard tier.
Basic is mostly for testing and development, not for production workloads.

These two tiers are further split into different series. For example, Basic tier has A-series. Standard tier VMs have many more series like A-, D-, and G-series. Among these series there are different sizes, which mean different amounts of CPU cores, RAM etc.

You might be a bit confused when a size like Large is mentioned. Sizes A0-A4 have alternative/old names like Small/Large etc. Others are named by their series and size.

You can find more info on VM sizes for example [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-windows-sizes/).

Comment: Answers my question partly. I am not confused with the term "large", but with the capabilities. As mentioned in my question above, how can A3 (4 cores, 7 GB RAM) belongs to Basic tier (1 core, 1.75 GB RAM). Also, you mentioned basic tier has A-series, precisely what I am looking for. Do we have any table/chart which mentions such relationship in detail?

Comment: This one is pretty good: http://www.virtualizationadmin.com/articles-tutorials/cloud-computing/microsoft/overview-virtual-machine-offerings-microsoft-azure.html

Answer (score 1):

It gets easier to understand if you simply forget you ever heard of "large" instances. Small, Medium, Large in regard to instance size is a holdover from the 'early' days.

- Instance(s) means the number of virtual machines
- VM Size (AKA Machine Size, Instance Size) = A0, A1, A2, A3, etc.. equates to the CPU, RAM and disk available on the VM

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-windows-sizes/

Basic vs. Standard - you pay less for basic because

- There is no load balancing or auto-scaling
- There are only 4 low end A class machine sizes available
- Disk performance is lower on Basic tier
- Basic Tier is most suitable for testing, development, etc.